# Colorbar/plotting issue? "posx and posy should be finite values"

Tags: python, arrays, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, colorbar

**The problem**

So I have a lat-lon array with `6` layers (`array.size = (192,288,6)`) containing a bunch of data ranging in values from nearly `0` to about `0.65`. When I plot data from every one of the `6` layers (`[:,:,0]`, `[:,:,1]`, etc.), I have no problems and get a nice map, except for `[:,:,4]`. For some reason, when I try to plot this 2D array, I get an error message I don't understand, and it only comes up when I try to include a colorbar. If I nix the colorbar there's no error, but I need that colorbar...

**The code**

Here's the code I use for a different part of the array, along with the resulting plot. Let's go with `[:,:,5]`.

```
#Set labels
lonlabels = ['0','45E','90E','135E','180','135W','90W','45W','0']
latlabels = ['90S','60S','30S','Eq.','30N','60N','90N']

#Set cmap properties
bounds = np.array([0,0.001,0.01,0.05,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6])
boundlabels = ['0','0.001','0.01','0.05','0.1','0.2','0.3','0.4','0.5','0.6']
cmap = plt.get_cmap('jet')
norm = colors.PowerNorm(0.35,vmax=0.65) #creates logarithmic scale

#Create basemap
fig,ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15.,10.))
m = Basemap(projection='cyl',llcrnrlat=-90,urcrnrlat=90,llcrnrlon=0,urcrnrlon=360.,lon_0=180.,resolution='c')
m.drawcoastlines(linewidth=2,color='w')
m.drawcountries(linewidth=2,color='w')
m.drawparallels(np.arange(-90,90,30.),linewidth=0.3)
m.drawmeridians(np.arange(-180.,180.,45.),linewidth=0.3)   
meshlon,meshlat = np.meshgrid(lon,lat)
x,y = m(meshlon,meshlat)

#Plot variables
trend = m.pcolormesh(x,y,array[:,:,5],cmap='jet',norm=norm,shading='gouraud')

#Set plot properties
#Colorbar
cbar=m.colorbar(trend, size='5%',ticks=bounds,location='bottom',pad=0.8)
cbar.set_label(label='Here is a label',size=25)
cbar.set_ticklabels(boundlabels)
for t in cbar.ax.get_xticklabels():
    t.set_fontsize(25)
#Titles & labels
ax.set_title('Here is a title for [:,:,5]',fontsize=35)
ax.set_xlabel('Longitude',fontsize=25)
ax.set_xticks(np.arange(0,405,45))
ax.set_xticklabels(lonlabels,fontsize=20)
ax.set_yticks(np.arange(-90,120,30))
ax.set_yticklabels(latlabels,fontsize=20)
```

[image]

Now when I use the EXACT same code but plot for `array[:,:,4]` instead of `array[:,:,5]`, I get this error.

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/linuxapps/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/formatters.pyc in __call__(self, obj)
    305                 pass
    306             else:
--> 307                 return printer(obj)
    308             # Finally look for special method names
    309             method = get_real_method(obj, self.print_method)

[lots of further traceback]

/linuxapps/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/text.pyc in draw(self, renderer)
    755             posy = float(textobj.convert_yunits(textobj._y))
    756             if not np.isfinite(posx) or not np.isfinite(posy):
--> 757                 raise ValueError("posx and posy should be finite values")
    758             posx, posy = trans.transform_point((posx, posy))
    759             canvasw, canvash = renderer.get_canvas_width_height()

ValueError: posx and posy should be finite values
```

I have no idea why it's doing this as my code for every other part of the array plots just fine, and they all use the same meshgrid. There are no `NaN`'s in the array. Also here's the result if I comment out all the code between `#Colorbar` and `#Titles & labels`

[image]

UPDATE: The problem also disappears when I include the colorbar code but changed the `PowerNorm` to `1.0` (`norm = colors.PowerNorm(1.0,vmax=0.65)`). Anything other than `1.0` generates the error when the colorbar is included.

**The question**

What could be causing the `posx` & `posy` error message, and how can I get rid of it so I can make this plot with the colorbar included?

**UPDATE**

When I run the kernel from scratch, again with the same code (except that I changed the `0.6` bound to `0.65`), I get the following warnings in the `array[:,:,4]` block. I'm not sure if they're related, but I'll include them just in case.

```
/linuxapps/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/colors.py:1202: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in power
  np.power(resdat, gamma, resdat)

[<matplotlib.text.Text at 0x2af62c8e6710>,
 <matplotlib.text.Text at 0x2af62c8ffed0>,
 <matplotlib.text.Text at 0x2af62cad8e90>,
 <matplotlib.text.Text at 0x2af62cadd3d0>,
 <matplotlib.text.Text at 0x2af62caddad0>,
 <matplotlib.text.Text at 0x2af62cae7250>,
 <matplotlib.text.Text at 0x2af62cacd050>]

/linuxapps/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/axis.py:1015:     UserWarning: Unable to find pixel distance along axis for interval padding of ticks; assuming no interval padding needed.
  warnings.warn("Unable to find pixel distance along axis "
/linuxapps/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/axis.py:1025:     UserWarning: Unable to find pixel distance along axis for interval padding of ticks; assuming no interval padding needed.
  warnings.warn("Unable to find pixel distance along axis "
```

Comment: Unfortunately without the array itself we can't really debug.  What does `np.isfinite(array[:,:,4])` show you? Can you examine the min and max of `array[:,:,4]`? i.e. do your `boundlabels` actually lie within the data for that slice?  Etc. etc.

Comment: "print np.where(np.isfinite(lintrends[:,:,4]) == False)" returns no array locations, so all the data is finite. np.max = 0.613478607374 and np.min = 4.4408920985e-15, so all the data lies between 0 and 0.65. (I changed 0.6 in the bounds to 0.65 and still get the same error.)

Answer (score 6):

So I found out that specifying `vmax` & `vmin` solves the problem. I have no idea why, but once I did, my plot turned out correctly with the colorbar.

```
trend = m.pcolormesh(x,y,array[:,:,5],cmap='jet',norm=norm,shading='gouraud',vmin=0.,vmax=0.6)
```

[image]

Comment: Noticed that too; your updates were interesting. Unfortunately there are [situations where specifying levels is absolutely necessary for the desired behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42723538/setting-matplotlib-colorbar-range-larger-range-than-the-values-plotted). Trying to figure out a workaround, but so far have come up dry. Just incredibly frustrating.