# Setting matplotlib colorbar range (larger range than the values plotted)

Tags: python, matplotlib, colorbar

I want to plot some data (between 0 and 18) but I want the colorbar to show a range between 0 and 40.
After going through several online examples, I have no idea on how to achieve what I need!

Here is a simple example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

rd = np.random.rand(40,100) # random samples from a uniform distribution over [0, 1]
surface = 18 * rd           # maximum value will be 18

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
cores = ax.contourf(surface[:], vmin=0, vmax=40)

cbar = plt.colorbar(cores)
```

I've tried this as well:

```
cbar = plt.colorbar(cores, extend='both', extendrect=True)
cbar.set_clim(0, 40.)
```

But I keep getting the same image, with a colorbar ranging from 0 to 20!
I know I could use the `set_over` method, but I don't want to get a single color... I want my whole color range (as defined in `cores`, from 0 to 40) to appear!

[image]

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I finally managed to solve it.
Instead of `vmin` and `vmax`, I must pass a keyword to control the levels to draw, like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

rd = np.random.rand(40,100)
surface = 18 * rd           # maximum value will be 18

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

cores = ax.contourf(surface[:], levels=range(41))
cbar = plt.colorbar(cores)

plt.show()
```

And I get the image I wanted:
[image]

Comment: Thanks so much! That was driving me absolutely crazy; I love how powerful matplotlib is, but the number of undocumented features and resulting unexpected behaviors can be absolutely infuriating.